# Boost video’s bass

Tags: iphone, audio, video, video-editing

How can I boost the bass of a video?

On my MacBook I’d use ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i in -af bass=g=15 out
```

But I haven’t found ffmpeg in the App Store for my phone.

iMovie on iPhone seems next to useless.

So, how can I change the audio EQ of videos on my phone?

I tried some online site but it errors every time so it’s probably broken, another site wants me to sign up which I don’t want to do. I couldn’t find an app for this myself, and the only way to get ffmpeg is apparently by jailbreaking but there’s no jailbreak for iOS 11.4.1 yet.

Comment: There is a media player for iOS based on FFmpeg 4.0. I know nothing about it but found it on a google search. You can check this out if you like. https://github.com/DeviLeo/DLGPlayer

Comment: There are also several sites that describe building ffmpeg for ios. I searched on "ffmpeg ios" using google.